# Undefined referenced when building a simple QT project

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, undefined-reference

I cannot compile a simple `main.cpp` file using CLion

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello QT!");
    label->show();
    int res = application.exec();
    delete label;
    return res;
}
```

this is the output

```
====================[ Build | Lab5_autogen | Debug ]============================
C:\Users\user\.CLion2019.1\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build "/cygdrive/d/user/workspace/CLionProjects/PDS_Cpp/Laboratorio 5/cmake-build-debug" --target Lab5_autogen -- -j 2
[100%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target Lab5
[100%] Built target Lab5_autogen

Build finished

====================[ Build | Lab5 | Debug ]====================================
C:\Users\user\.CLion2019.1\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build "/cygdrive/d/user/workspace/CLionProjects/PDS_Cpp/Laboratorio 5/cmake-build-debug" --target Lab5 -- -j 2
[ 25%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target Lab5
[ 25%] Built target Lab5_autogen
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable Lab5.exe
CMakeFiles/Lab5.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(QArrayData*)':
C:/Qt/5.12.3/mingw73_64/include/QtCore/qarraydata.h:239: undefined reference to `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
C:/Qt/5.12.3/mingw73_64/include/QtCore/qarraydata.h:239:(.text$_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData[_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData]+0x1c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Lab5.dir/build.make:103: Lab5.exe] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/Lab5.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/Lab5.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: Lab5] Error 2
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Lab5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Charts REQUIRED)

list(APPEND LIBRARIES
        Qt5::Core
        Qt5::Gui
        Qt5::Widgets
        Qt5::Charts)
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES LIBRARIES)

add_executable(Lab5 "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(Lab5 ${LIBRARIES})
```

and I've added this line

```
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Qt\5.12.3\mingw73_64\lib\cmake
```

in `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake -> CMake options`

I'm pretty sure I don't need a `.pro` file, my teacher was able to compile this project without it.

**UPDATE**
I've set MinGW as the default compiler using
`C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64`

but the window is not created and I get this output

```
"D:\user\workspace\CLionProjects\PDS_Cpp\Laboratorio 5\cmake-build-debug\Lab5.exe"

Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

Previously I was compiling using cygwin

Comment: So, you got it to build now? I'd suggest using Qt Creator, it supports qmake, and Qt comes with mingw support, so it'll be very easy to do all this using Qt Creator. Your problems may come from using clion.

Comment: Have you googled for `0xC0000135`

Comment: So I first had to do two things, first setting a a correct Path to MinGW, and second create a new `.pro` file using `qmake -project`. Now I have a `.ui` created using Designer, how can I add automatically the header file to my project folder? In the CMake I put `set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)` but it won't generate any header file when I build

Comment: In the preferred mode (where you specify a different build folder from the source) `CMake` generates in the build folder which should be different from the source folder.

Comment: @drescherjm is there a way to set CMake to save the `ui_` and `moc_` files into the source directory rather than into the `cmake-build` directory?

Comment: I don't know. I have never wanted that feature since it goes against having your project in a git repository where you don't want any generated files in the repository.